# How to make no space between collection cells?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, size-classes

I am using auto layout and size class.The width is compact and the screen width is 375.I have four pictures one line. So cell width is 93 and little space between them.But I wang no space.Maybe display 5 pictures one line? How to display 5 pictures each line? or other solution?

There is no code used here and I don't have enough reputation to post image.Please don't vote down...

Comment: it would be better if you share some picture of the story board or some codes which you have tried till now..so that we can try to solve your problem

Comment: @Bluewings There is no code used here and I don't have enough reputation to post image.Please don't vote down...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your cells to adjust their width, you'll need to calculate the flow layout's `itemSize` based on the view width.

- **If all your cells will be the same size**, you can set the flow layout's `itemSize` property.

  This would be the easiest solution for your question, as you can determine an integral width for a specific number of pictures per line to avoid any gaps between the pictures.
- **If you need to calculate per-cell sizes**, you can do it in the `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` delegate.

You can recalculate the itemSize when the device orientation changes and update the layout:

- **Redraw layout without animation:**

  `[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]`
- **Animate layout changes:**

  `[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil]`